# regex match all but not specific string

Tags: regex

I have some xml file and want to remove everything but a specific string.

There are quite other similar questions at StackOverflow but none of them works for my file and after a few hours of trying different regex I would like to ask for a help.

so far the closest regex which succeeded partly but not completely is:

```
^((?!<query.*<\/query>).)*$
```

a sample of the xml file:

```
      <search>
          <query>index=_internal [`set_local_host`] source=*license_usage.log* type="Usage" | eval h=if(len(h)=0 OR isnull(h),"(SQUASHED)",h) | eval s=if(len(s)=0 OR isnull(s),"(SQUASHED)",s) | eval idx=if(len(idx)=0 OR isnull(idx),"(UNKNOWN)",idx) | bin _time span=1d | stats sum(b) as b by _time, pool, s, st, h, idx   | timechart span=1d sum(b) AS volumeB by st fixedrange=false  | join type=outer _time [search index=_internal [`set_local_host`] source=*license_usage.log* type="RolloverSummary"  | eval _time=_time - 43200 | bin _time span=1d | stats latest(stacksz) AS "stack size" by _time] | fields - _timediff  | foreach * [eval &lt;&lt;FIELD&gt;&gt;=round('&lt;&lt;FIELD&gt;&gt;'/1024/1024/1024, 3)] </query>
          <earliest>$central_time.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$central_time.latest$</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.axisLabelsX.majorLabelStyle.overflowMode">ellipsisNone</option>
        <option name="charting.chart.stackMode">stacked</option>
        <option name="charting.chart.style">shiny</option>
        <option name="trellis.scales.shared">1</option>
        <option name="trellis.size">medium</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>index=_introspection  sourcetype=splunk_resource_usage component=hostwide saxsa
| eval tcu = ('data.cpu_system_pct' + 'data.cpu_user_pct')
| timechart limit=0 span=1d avg(tcu) by host</query>
          <earliest>$central_time.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$central_time.latest$</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
```

I use regex101 so the sample can be paste there in order to see why the rex is working only partly. To tell shortly , it doesn't match the first occurrence of  but it matches the second occurrence. What I expect is that the regex does not match any of the occurrence of `<query>.*</query>`

fx. I want to match anything but not the following string:

```
<query>anything between(can be multiple lines*)</query>
```

Comment: Can you update the question to specify *what* you're trying to match within the XML file? Currently you only gave the XML string and the reqular expression but I don't see any `<query>` tags in the XML string provided. What specific string are you referring to?

Comment: I've just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response. Partially because I'm at work, partially due to the fact that this type of situation was actually rather new to me (I *love* regular expressions, but I haven't had any exposure to this situation so it's a learning experience for both of us), but I *think* I may have a solution that you're looking for.

What I basically tried to do was use a bit of recursion in the expression with a combination of a negative look-ahead and negative lookbehind to ensure I'm not capturing any `<query>` tags

```
<(?!query).*(?<!<\/query)(?R)*>
```

- `<` - Matches the literal character `<` to match the beginning of an opening tag
- `(?!query)` - matches the all of the text opening tags proceeding `<` excluding `query`
- `.*` - Matches all of the characters (including the `>` of the opening tag) up until:
- `(?<!<\/query)` which is a negative look-behind assertion to ensure I'm not getting text from the `.*` with anything before a `</query` closing tag (note the missing `>`).
- `(?R)*` - This is the part that took me a while to wrap my mind around so I may possibly butcher this explanation because I haven't used this before. Whatever the pattern is BEFORE this pattern, it recurses the entire regular expression from the current string position. Now I know that sounded confusing because it was (still is *slightly*) confusing to me too. But, I believe once `<(?!query).*(?<!<\/query)` finds it's first match, which would be `<search>`, from there, it repeats that entire pattern from the end of `<search>`. Thus, it will then check for an opening `<query` and a closing `</query` tag. And if it finds it, it skips it.
- `>` - Matches the literal closing tag `>`, in which if the XML is written correctly, it should match `<search`'s closing tag.

Test of your example with the following regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/UqP9Tr/1)

I sincerely hope this helps!

Comment: Chris, I also like very much regex but just as you have not been exposed so much on match but type regex so it is a bit of challenge for me but you seem to see deeper then me:D. 
Your solution is working perfect so I accepted it and thank you for very nice explanation. I used some time to figure recursion as well and think it needs more exercise to get it better.. 
Thank you again:)

Comment: After a few more hours playing with similar type regex I found out that actually there is possible solution without recursion for that issue: <(?!query>).*(?<!\/query)>
Its same as yours but wh. (?R)* 
Anyway, nice to have both.